# Loop list and open file if found

Tags: python, loops, csv, python-2.x

Not sure where to start with this... I know how to read in a csv file but if I have a heap of files in the same directory, how can read them in according to whether they are in a list. For example, a list such as...

```
l= [['file1.csv','title1','1'], ['file2.csv','title2','1'],['file3.csv','title3','1']]
```

How can I get just those 3 files even though I up to 'file20.csv' in the directory.
Can I somehow loop through the list and use an if-statement to check the filenames and open the file if found?

Comment: Which programming language do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

```py
for filedesc in l: #go over each sublist in l
    fname, ftitle, _ = filedesc #unpack the information contained in it
    with open(fname) as f: #open the file with the appropriate name
        reader = csv.reader(f) #create reader of that file
        #go about bussiness
```

Comment: Thanks @HennyH but can i ask, do I need to unpack all the info or can't I search by the filename occurring in the first column ie. file1.csv.

Answer (score 0):

An updated post because I've gotten so close with this....

```
lfiles= []
csvfiles=[]
for row in l:
    lfiles= row[0]      #This reads in just the filesnames from list 'l' 
with open(lfiles) as x:
    inread = csv.reader(x)
    for i in x:
        print i
```

That's print everything in the files that were read in, but now I want to append 'csvfiles' (an empty list) with a row if a particular column equals something.
Probably like this...????

```
for i in x:
    for line in i:
        if line= 'ThisThingAppears5Times':
            csvfiles.append(line)  # and now the 5 lines are in a 2dlist
```

Of course that doesn't work but close??